# How to clean install the macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina

I want to clean install the Catalina but there is `Macintosh HD - Data` so I'm confused to deal with this extra partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> macOS Catalina runs on a dedicated, read-only system volume called
>   Macintosh HD. This volume is completely separate from all other data
>   to help prevent the accidental overwriting of critical operating
>   system files. Your files and data are stored in another volume named
>   Macintosh HD - Data. In the Finder, both volumes appear as Macintosh
>   HD.
>   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650

Then, these are the procedure.

- Click the Macintosh HD - Data (1) then click the minus above the Volume (2)
  [image]
- Click the Macintosh HD (1) then click the Erase (2)
  [image]

The rest is the same as usual.

Copy right of the images: https://qiita.com/PaSeRi/items/59e9785580dbd518ac93